# print data from a TXT text file

Tags: python

the following function should print some data it fetches from a TXT file

```
    def viewList():
            entryLogic = open('files/agenda.txt','r')
            for line in entryLogic : 
                line = line.rstrip()  
                print(line, end="" +"\n")
            entryLogic .close()
```

the file data is in this format

```
jose,999,999 
andres,1008,340
```

when using the function, the data should come out as follows:

```
jose
999
999
andres
1083
340
```

what is the correct way to do the function so that it prints in the format that it should appear?

Comment: You need to split the line, and then print each of its components accordingly.
`comp = line.split(',')` then loop over comp and print them.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only print as you shown.

```
def viewList(filename='files/agenda.txt'):
    with open(filename,'r') as entry_logic:
        print('\n'.join([_ for r in entry_logic for _ in r.rstrip().split(',')]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as Ben Y proposed, you should just do:

```
def viewList():
    entryLogic = open('files/agenda.txt', 'r')
    for line in entryLogic: 
        for v in line.split(','): 
            print(v)
    entryLogic.close()
```